# jquery autocomplete - need enter key to process current search phrase

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

When I have a list of suggestions from autocomplete I need to allow the user to just press enter to process the search term they keyed in or click on one of the suggestions. Now pressing the enter key seems to submit the form (which does not have an action).

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

     $('#SearchPhrase').autocomplete({
            source: function(query, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/services/search.cfc?method=getMessages&returnformat=json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        term: query.term
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        response(result);
                    }
                });
            }
            ,
            minLength: 3,
            select: function(event, ui) {
               alert(ui.item.value);
            $.ajax({
                    url: "/services/search.cfc?method=getMessages2&returnformat=json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        term: ui.item.value
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        alert(result.id);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).keydown(function(e){
            if (e.keyCode === 13){
                alert('enter was pressed');
                event.preventDefault();
                 $.ajax({
                    url: "/services/search.cfc?method=getMessages2&returnformat=json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        term: $('#SearchPhrase').val()
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        alert(result.id);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        });
</script>
```

Comment: And your question is.....???

Comment: How can I allow the enter key to process the current search phrase and not submit the form.

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` should be `e.preventDefault()` as you have passed through `e` not `event`

Comment: Good catch.  But, the page still submits without processing the ajax call.

Comment: You can try with event.stopPropagation() to prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

Comment: I think Pete may have gotten it right.  My alert(result.id) was showing "undefined".  I guess that threw me off track. It appears that the form is not submitting now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
function sendSelected(_val){
   var search_input = _val;
   if (search_input =='') search_input ='*';
   var dataString = 'keyword='+search_input;

   if (search_input.length > 2 || search_input=='*') {
      $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "core/functions/searchdata.php",
           data: dataString,
           success: function(server_response) {
               $('#searchresultdata').empty();
               $('#searchresultdata').append(server_response);
               $('span#category_title').html(search_input);
           }
       });
   }
}

$("#SearchPhrase").keypress(function(e) {
 if(e.keyCode == 13)
 {
     e.preventDefault();
     sendSelected(this.value);
     $(this).autocomplete('close');
 }
```

});